# Unity collision of one object with another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a code, I need that when the `player_` object touches the object with the `bomb` tag, the following actions occur, but when the `bg_` object touches the object with the `bomb` tag, nothing should happen, how to write it?

```
public class Player_ : MonoBehaviour{

public GameObject player_;
public GameObject bg_;

public static bool lose = false;

void Awake(){
    lose = false;
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other){
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "bomb")
        lose = true;
        player_.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        bg_.gameObject.SetActive (false);

}

}
```

Comment: Does your ``Player`` and ``Bomb`` both have an object collider?

Comment: @ItzHex Of course, I just need to exclude bg_ from the condition

Comment: Your ``if`` statement should exclude ``bg_`` from the condition. Are you sure your ``_bg`` object doesn't have the ``bomb`` tag?

Comment: No, ''bg_'' has a ''bg'' tag

Comment: Is the code inside your ``if`` statement being run or not?

Comment: Yes, but it is executed immediately due to the fact that bg_ (background) touches the bombs, I need these actions to be performed only when the player touches the bombs

Comment: Your ``Player_.cs`` file is attached to the player object, correct? ``OnTriggerEnter2D`` should only be called when the object the script is attached to collides with an object with a trigger collider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While tags will work for your need, I'd like to caution against using them.

Instead, utilize [Layer Based Collision](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html), and use layers instead of tags. This effectively does the same thing, but it actually prevents physics interactions entirely, preventing wasted computing power.

Rather than adding a tag to the player, instead create a layer for "Player" and a layer for "Interactables" (or "Bombs" if you only have the player interacting with bombs). Set the layers respectively, and modify the collision matrix so that only things on the Player can collide with Interactables. This way, other objects won't even trigger a collision and you don't need to build logic to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

On your bomb, you could have a OnTriggerEnter2D and when something triggers it, you simply look the tag and do the proper reaction.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other){
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        Do Something();
    }
}
```

This way, when something else triggers it, nothing happen